# How to set custom bcc/to field for Devise Mailer emails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I would like include the first and last name of my users in the to/bcc headers of all emails sent out via Devise.

I looked at this https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/mailers/helpers.rb#L28

It seems that Devise also assigns the to field as `@email` in the template. How would I go about overriding the header so that emails are sent out with to/bcc headers `"FirstName LastName <email@example.com>"`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would start by looking at [How-To:-Use-custom-mailer](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-custom-mailer)

To use a custom mailer, create a class that extends Devise::Mailer, like this:

```
class MyMailer < Devise::Mailer   
  helper :application # gives access to all helpers defined within `application_helper`.
  include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers # Optional. eg. `confirmation_url`
  default template_path: 'devise/mailer' # to make sure that your mailer uses the devise views
end
```

Then, in your config/initializers/devise.rb, set `config.mailer` to `"MyMailer"`.

```
def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
  opts[:to] = 'fname lname<email@example.com>'
  opts[:bcc] = 'fname lname<email@example.com>'
  super
end
```

I hope that this helps and set you in the right direction